# Como redirecionar dominio .com com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Tenho 2 dominios, example.com e example.com.br apontando para o mesmo site wordpress.

Gostaria de redirecionar toda vez que alguem entrar em example.com, seja redirecionado para example.com.br/en

Achei esse código, mas ele redireciona também o example.com.br para o /en

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com.br/en [L,R=301]
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

P.S: De preferencia funcione tanto com 'www', como sem.

Comment: Boa tarde @AmadeuAntunes acho que não seja uma duplicata desta pergunta especifica.

Answer (score 1):

Isso deve ajudar.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com.br/en [R=301,L]
```

Ou tenta assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com.br/en [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Neste caso o .com.br também redireciona, e eu só quero que o .com redirecione.

Comment: Bom, é simples, coloque este .htaccess somente no root do .com ou simplesmente crie um index de redirecionamento em cada.
Se os 2 apontam para a mesma hospedagem fica fácil.

Comment: Os 2 DNS fazem parte da mesma hospedagem, apontados diretamente pelo apache para o mesmo directorio. Então os 2 vão ler a mesma regra do htaccess.

Comment: Sua hospedagem tem cPanel? Se tem, você pode criar redirecionamentos diretamente no cPanel.

Comment: vou postar outra maneira editando a pergunta, olha lá.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, mas eu achei uma solição através de um plugin do próprio WP. Agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: Tranquilo. Sempre é bom procurar soluções alternativas do provável.